# Modulus of solutions to fourth-degree equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The equation $z^4-6z+3=0$ has four complex solutions. How many of them satisfy $1<|z|<2$?

I am trying to apply [Rouche's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem). On the boundary $|z|=2$, we have $|-6z+3|\leq 15<16=|z^4|$, so $z^4-6z+3$ has the same number of zeros inside $|z|<2$, which is $4$.

Now what can I do with the $|z|\leq 1$ part? Now it is not true that $|z^4|>|-6z+3|$.

Comment: What did you learnt in the course? I suppose you are learning complex analysis and this question is standard.

Comment: @John I took a look at the theorems and I think Rouche seems closest to this. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Oh I think on $|z|=1$, we have the opposite: $|6z-3|>|z|^4$. So the number of roots there is $1$!

Comment: Yes, you've got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(z)=z^4$ and $g(z)=3-6z$ then $|f(z)|> |g(z)|$ on $|z|=2$ so by Rouches Theorem $f$ and $f+g$ has same number of roots inside $|z|<2$ which is $4$.

Now, $|g(z|>|f(z)|$ on $|z|=1$ so by Rouches Theorem $g$ and $f+g$ has the same number of roots in $|z|<1$ which is $1$

So Clearly in $1<|z|<2$, $f+g=z^4-6z+3$ has $3$ roots[image: Rouches Theorem]